# Store reference to non-NDB object in an NDB model

Tags: python, google-app-engine

As a caveat: I am an utter novice here.  I wouldn't be surprised to learn a) this is already answered, but I can't find it because I lack the vocabulary to describe my problem or b) my question is basically silly to begin with, because what I want to do is silly.

Is there some way to store a reference to a class instance that defined and stored in active memory and *not* stored in NDB?  I'm trying to write an app that would help manage a number of characters/guilds in an MMO.  I have a class, CharacterClass, that includes properties such as armor, name, etc. that I define in main.py as a base python object, and then define the properties for each of the classes in the game. Each Character, which would be stored in Datastore, would have a property charClass, which would be a reference to one of those instances of CharacterClass.  In theory I would be able to do things like

```
if character.charClass.armor == "Cloth":
```

while storing the potentially hundreds of unique characters and their specifc data in Datastore, but without creating a copy of "Cloth" for every cloth-armor character, or querying Datastore for what kind of armor a mage wears thousands of times a day.

I don't know what kind of NDB property to use in Character to store the reference to the applicable CharacterClass.  Or if that's the right way to do it, even.  Thanks for taking the time to puzzle through my confused question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string is all you need.  You just need to fetch the class based on the string value.  You could create a custom property that automatically instantiates the class on reference.

However I have a feeling that hard coding the values in code might be a bit unwieldy.  May be you character class instances should be datastore entities as well. It means you can adjust these parameters without deploying new code.

If you want these objects in memory then you can pre-cache them on warmup.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the problem with my thinking was not really grasping how memcache works; as you say, trying to hard-code these is somewhat pointless, since this data will be heavily used and so should just stay in memcache.